# Laravel 5 - route not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am studying Laravel 5 now.

I have add new route as following:

```
Route::get('items', function () {
    // test code
});

Route::get('items/create', function () {
    echo "test";
    die();
    // test code
});
```

And I tried show my code on my webbrowser(http://localhost:8000/items/create).
But I have got 503 error. And http://localhost:8000/items works fine.
How can I fix it?
Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `return "test";` instead of `echo` and `die`.

Comment: If what @samlev above is saying is not working (404) then perhaps you have to clear route cache with `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Route::get('items/create', function () {
    return "test";
});
```